# Best way to get every Xth id from Django model?

Tags: python, django, model

I need to be able to get every (for example) 100th id from a Django model. So far the only thing I've found to do that is the following:

`ids = MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)[::100]`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `where` and the `modulo` operator.

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["id %% 100 == 0"]).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

The double % is because we need to escape it as it's a reserved character for parameters.

Comment: Is this the better approach in the pythonic sense of 'better'? Also, how is this in terms of speed? Would this be quicker than doing it the way I listed above?

Thanks for the input either way :D

Comment: To me this isn't very "Django-y" because it's probably database specific. I know it works with Postgres, I would assume MySQL, but I have no idea about the rest. However, in terms of speed this is faster because it's doing the filter at the database level rather than at the app/python level.